# Gmail & Google Docs: Paste just the text, not the formatting (Firefox, Safari)

Tags: gmail, google-docs

When I use Gmail and Google Docs (With Firefox 3.6.6), I often cut text from another HTML or PDF document.

When I paste this text into the document body, Gmail and Google doc will paste the text *and* the formatting. I almost never want to copy the formatting from another document, and I instead need to clean up the formatting afterwards.

Is there a magic key combination so that I can just paste the text, and *not* the formatting? <strike>(RANT: That's a dumb default behavior, and is becoming more common ever since Word switched to this behavior many years ago. How often do people want to copy the formatting?)</strike> Can I make this the default behavior for my Gmail or Google Doc editor?

I assume this behavior is mostly within the Google Application. I am also assuming that this behavior is common across most Google Apps. If this is actually a web-browser <strike>bug</strike> feature, let me know.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It seems that the browser must enable this feature.

Chrome/Firefox, PC: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Chrome/Firefox, Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Safari, Mac: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

It's not a webapp answer, but I use a program called [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/). It just sits in your system tray and provides a hotkey (configurable) that will paste the current clipboard contents as plain text. I absolutely love this feature. I have it set to `WINDOWS+v`

Answer (score 3):

Alas the add-on "Copy Plain Text" by Jeremy Gillick (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-plain-text/) does not do the trick. As the name says, it "Copies text without formatting...". The question here is about pasting. Yes, this is different if your source is not a browser.

I did not find a firefox extension to help here. But [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) does it. Thanks to EndangeredMassa for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of Gmail/Google Docs there is a keyboard shortcut for pasting without source formatting:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you're the sort of person who always has a terminal window open, and you're on OSX or another OS with shell commands that give you pipe-access to the system clipboard, you can set up something like this:

```
alias stripstyle='pbpaste | pbcopy'
```

Then whenever you want to paste without formatting, just go into your terminal and type `stripstyle` and voila, whatever's in the clipboard is deformatted.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to open a tab of Google Translate, paste it there, and cut from there, and then paste to where I need (Gmail, Docs, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

As @eagle mentioned, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will work in Chrome.  There is an addon for Firefox that claims it will solve your problem: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/134/

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox with the Adblock Plus extension installed, you need to do a little configuration first.

1. Type in `about:config` to the address bar and press enter.
2. Accept a warning about being careful, if it appears.
3. Search for `extensions.adblockplus.sidebar_key`.
4. Change the value to just `Accel Shift U` instead of `Accel Shift V, Accel Shift U`.

If you also use the [Resurrect Pages](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resurrect-pages/) extension, you may want to pick something other than U.

AdblockPlus [decided years ago](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11217) they would leave this conflict in place.