# Fixed text size in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, font

I'm using Google Docs and usually when I paste text into the document the text size varies. I can select all and set the font size, but this slowly gets annoying.

Is there any way we can set a "fixed" font size for a document?

(In other words when I paste text from other sources in, the font size is still uniform throughout.)

Comment: Related http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3464/gmail-google-docs-paste-just-the-text-not-the-formatting-firefox-safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, you can also paste text using "Paste and Match Style" which is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on a Mac. This usually works for me, resulting in the pasted text all having the default font and font size of the Google doc.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy/paste from a Word document or an HTML page, the clipboard contains rich text. You need to convert it back to plain text if you don't want to keep the formatting rules.

You have two alternatives:

1. Use a plain text editor, such as Notepad, TextMate (please note Word is not a plain text editor). Copy the content, paste it into the text editor to cleanup formatting, then copy it again and paste it in Google Docs.
2. Copy and paste the content into Google Docs, then select the text, go to the `Format` menu and click on Clear formatting.

[image: Google Docs Clear Formatting]

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm, try using Windows Notepad, as it removes all formatteed texts and gives you simple text. select the text you want to copy by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then copy that text by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, go to Notepad, now click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, then again click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> if you want to cut the text from Notepad & finally go to Google docs and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it, hope this helps you out.

Comment: Do you mean **everytime** I want to paste stuff in I had to do that?

Comment: Yes you've to, but it's not that hard to do it yeah :)

Comment: [This Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cekbgkmeapobkbadclnkjfjdbpbcaobd) (among others) offers the ability to copy text with any formatting stripped. Assuming you're copying from a browser window of some sort, this should save a little work.